# Which bootstrap version i should use in reactjs, getting confusion to use

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using plain bootstrap in reactjs, but some of the attributes are not working in reactjs so what should i do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this guide to use bootstrap with react: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-bootstrap/

or you can use this package: https://reactstrap.github.io/  that have stateless react components for Bootstrap 4, ready to use in your react app.